# If statement only works on the first instance

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an IF statement very similar to this Fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/fz4wF/43/

What I'm wanting to know is, how do I display the `alert()` only once ALL divs with the `.ccn` class have a value over 1000, not just the first instance. I have tried the `each()` function but I'm not too sure how to use it.

```js
$(".ccn").keyup(function() {
  if ($(".ccn").val() >= 1000)
    alert('test');
});
```

```html
<div class="cardNumber">
  <input type="text" value="" maxlength="4" name="ccn" class="ccn">
  <input type="text" value="" maxlength="4" name="ccn" class="ccn">
  <input type="text" value="" maxlength="4" name="ccn" class="ccn">
  <input type="text" value="" maxlength="4" name="ccn" class="ccn">
</div>

<ul>
  <li class="checkNumber">Card Number</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Use `if ($(this).val() >= 1000)`. In your case, it will always give value of first element which matches the selector. Also use `parseInt`

Answer (score 3):

Try the following codes:

```
 $('.cnn').on('keyup', function() {
    flag = true;
    $.each($('.cnn'), function(index, input) {
        if (parseInt($(input).val()) <= 1000){
            flag = false
        }
    })

    if(flag) {
        alert();
    }
})
```

First, you need to add event listener on those input elements. keyup, keydown, change, input events are fired when user type in those inputs.

Then, when user type in those input you can validate each input one by one to see if all of them satisfied your condition(>1000). Although this is not so good to validate value every time user types. You might need a throttle function so that you can check their values every duration time.

Comment: code only answer is not good.. better to post some explanations too.

Comment: Thanks for that. I have a new question now - http://stackoverflow.com/q/35049834/4674452

Answer (score 1):

> Use `.filter()` which will return only those elements which pass the provided condition in function.

Also note, you should use `parseInt` with base(radix) to cast input to `Integer`

Try this:

```js
$(".ccn").keyup(function() {
  var len = $(".ccn").filter(function() {
    return parseInt($(this).val(), 10) >= 1000;
  }).length;
  if ($('.ccn').length == len) {
    alert('Passed');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cardNumber">
  <input type="text" value="" maxlength="4" name="ccn" class="ccn">
  <input type="text" value="" maxlength="4" name="ccn" class="ccn">
  <input type="text" value="" maxlength="4" name="ccn" class="ccn">
  <input type="text" value="" maxlength="4" name="ccn" class="ccn">
</div>

<ul>
  <li class="checkNumber">Card Number</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: _how do I display the alert() only once ALL divs with the .ccn class have a value over 1000_ may be you missed this i guess.

Comment: Note that the OP is looking to know when *all* the inputs have a value > 1000, not just the current one.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over all the `input` elements as @jilykate suggested, or alternatively you could use `filter()` to see how many have the value you require and compare the number of those to the total. You will also need to use `parseInt()` to convert the string returned from the value of the element to a number for comparison. Try this:

```js
$(".ccn").keyup(function() {
  var $ccn = $('.ccn');
  var $validCcn = $ccn.filter(function() {
    return parseInt(this.value, 10) >= 1000;
  });

  if ($ccn.length == $validCcn.length)
    alert('test');
});
```

```html
<div class="cardNumber">
  <input type="text" value="" maxlength="4" name="ccn" class="ccn">
  <input type="text" value="" maxlength="4" name="ccn" class="ccn">
  <input type="text" value="" maxlength="4" name="ccn" class="ccn">
  <input type="text" value="" maxlength="4" name="ccn" class="ccn">
</div>

<ul>
  <li class="checkNumber">Card Number</li>
</ul>
```